# SWIFTUI overlay pointer (mouse) ipad

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ipad, mouse

I want to change the pointer view of the tablet I succeed of changing the pointer (mouse) view with UIBezierPath like this

```
   let pointer = PointerInteractionView()
       var body: some View {
    HomeView()
        .environmentObject(mainApp)
        .environmentObject(externalDisplayContent)

    .navigationTitle("Screens")
    .overlay(pointer)

 }

 struct PointerInteractionView: UIViewRepresentable {
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView()
    let interaction = UIPointerInteraction(delegate: context.coordinator)
    view.addInteraction(interaction)
    return view
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}

func makeCoordinator() -> CustomPointerDelegate {
    CustomPointerDelegate()
}
 }

 class CustomPointerDelegate: NSObject, UIPointerInteractionDelegate {
func pointerInteraction(_ interaction: UIPointerInteraction, styleFor region: UIPointerRegion) -> UIPointerStyle? {
    // Customize the pointer shape
    let customShape = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50), cornerRadius: 10)
    let pointerShape = UIPointerShape.path(customShape)
    
    // Create the pointer style
    let pointerStyle = UIPointerStyle(shape: pointerShape)
    
    return pointerStyle
}
}
```

When I overlay the view nothing is clickable on the application, so the solution I found is to use this: `.overlay(pointer.allowsHitTesting(false))`

but when I use pointer.allowsHitTesting(false) I lost my custom view of the pointer

how can I keep my click interaction and keep my custom pointer view?

I tried another approach to set the pointer style but i have exactly the same problem, all the other views are not clickable when setting the pointer view:

```
   struct CustomPointerView: UIViewRepresentable {
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView()
    
    // Customize the appearance of the pointer
   // view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
   // view.layer.borderWidth = 2
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.withAlphaComponent(0)
    
    // Enable pointer interaction
    let interaction = UIPointerInteraction(delegate: context.coordinator)
    view.addInteraction(interaction)
    
    return view
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator()
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPointerInteractionDelegate {
    func pointerInteraction(_ interaction: UIPointerInteraction, regionFor request: UIPointerRegionRequest, defaultRegion: UIPointerRegion) -> UIPointerRegion? {
        // Define custom pointer region if needed
        return defaultRegion
    }
    
    func pointerInteraction(_ interaction: UIPointerInteraction, styleFor region: UIPointerRegion) -> UIPointerStyle? {
        // Customize the pointer shape
        let customShape = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50), cornerRadius: 10)
        let pointerShape = UIPointerShape.path(customShape)
        
        // Create the pointer style
        let pointerStyle = UIPointerStyle(shape: pointerShape)
        
        return pointerStyle
    }
  }
 }
```

And I call it like this:

```
Color.clear // Use Color.clear for a transparent background
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all).background(CustomPointerView()) // Fill the entire screen
```